# Supposing Google uses GTFS format for Directions service, how does it represent the actual bus route?

Tags: google-maps, format, general-transit-feed-specification

So I am actually taking a look right now at Google's GTFS format for public means of transport. But from my point of view, I can see information included about the position of the bus stops and some generic info about the "trips" as they call them, but how do they get to represent the right route that connects two stops on Google Maps?

Maybe shapes.txt is used for that? Is it though?

Comment: In what country, and what route? For the most part they don't. It is just straight lines between stops: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Stirling,+UK/Dollar,+Clackmannanshire,+UK/@56.1437259,-3.9112351,16z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x488857d73c437831:0xfbf01f3702d576ad!2m2!1d-3.9369029!2d56.1165227!1m5!1m1!1s0x4886295e6e58d809:0x84d9187f281e78cc!2m2!1d-3.677553!2d56.163937!3e3

Comment: @Vesanto It is actually a generic question. Can someone specify the exact route through GTFS?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the shapes.txt files contains the geometry to be displayed. It is referred to in the trips by the shape_id field.
See https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#routes_fields